# Chicago or APA for draft manuscript?

Tags: writing, writing-style, reference-managers

I am relatively new to the writing process. I wrote my first manuscript in APA style and found it time consuming while changing it to the Chicago manual style. I am aware that most journals have their own specific journal styles that we have to follow despite the reference style being the same. However, as per your experiences, in which style of referencing/writing, did you find writing your draft manuscript easier to modify later on? (Modify as in changing styles). Simply put, should I write my draft manuscript in APA or Chicago? P.S. Political Science Pre-PhD student.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed - it's an XY problem than Jeromy has answered well.

Answer (score 15):

My main tip would be to use a reference manager that automates the task of formatting references. There are [many to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software). But any good tool should make it fairly trivial to move between author-date format to numbered format. Good tools should also come with a wide range of tools for customising the look and feel of your references. Personally, I use Endnote and it works well for my workflow with MS Word. If you use LaTeX, then you'd want something that works better with BibTeX. That said, I think the big thing is that you get to know the features of your reference manager so you can use it effectively.

In terms of what reference format to adopt, I'd go with the format required by where you plan to submit the work. If it's a thesis, then follow any rules provided by your department. But commonly with PhDs, the format is up to you. In that case, you'd usually adopt the convention (or one of the conventions) of your discipline.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Jeromy. The best way to address this issue is to use a reference manager. If you use a word processor [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) may be a good alternative. It is free and open-source and has an extensive reference library making it easy to download different styles and format your manuscript.

LaTeX with BibLatex/Biber (Bibtex-successor) is even more precise and reliable with regards to formatting references. However, in the social sciences there is very few journals that accept LaTeX submissions with means that you have to convert it to a word file which can be a pain.